# In computing the range of raw scores, if the lowest value is 0. Should I still use it as my lowest value to find the range?

Tags: range

My professor gave us the raw scores. We need to find the range. The highest value is 93 and the lowest is 0.

Here's the raw scores

66,85,40,5,12,12,18,23,1,15,1,6,81,50, 21,0,27,5,13,0,24,22,5,1,32,12,23,93,38,29,16,0,36

We are asked to find the range, class interval, and the size of the class interval. I just want to know if I should use the value 0 (which is the lowest) in computing the range. Thank you!

Comment: Answer posted, but why would you not want to use zero? Perhaps I can edit my answer to more specifically address your concerns.

Answer (score 1):

**Most definitely use zero.**

Your values range from $0$ to $93$, so to give a range of $1$ to $93$ would be incorrect.